# MacOS Brew unable to update or remove temurin

Tags: macos, package, homebrew, homebrew-cask, eclipse-temurin

I'm no longer able to update or remove temurin, this is what I see.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Raycast:

[image]

```
Error: temurin: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_rename - 
(/usr/local/Caskroom/temurin/21,35, /usr/local/Caskroom/temurin/21,35.upgrading)
```

Can you give me a hand?